# How to split a single docker-compose yml file to multiple yml files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to split a single YML file  into multiple YML files:

**Microservice.yml:**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------
#- Docker compose base definition file to run containers.
#-----------------------------------------------------------
---
version: '3.6'
services:

  db-service1:
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_DB_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    container_name: 'mongo1'
    ports:
      - "30001:27017"

  db-service2:
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_DB_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    container_name: 'mongo2'
    ports:
      - "30002:27017"

  db-service3:
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_DB_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    container_name: 'mongo3'
    ports:
      - "30003:27017"


  mongosetup:
    container_name: 'mongoinit'
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_INIT_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db-service1
      - db-service2
      - db-service3
  
  api:
    build:
      context: ${API_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        API_BASE_IMAGE: ${API_BASE_IMAGE}
        api_artifactid: ${api_artifactid}
        api_java_options: ${java_options} ${REMOTE_DEBUG}
    image: ${API_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db-service1
      - db-service2
      - db-service3
    ports:
      - "9096:8080"
      - "40508:40500"
    environment:
      DATABASE_KEY: mongodb
      MONGODB_DBNAME: ms_eventclassification
      MONGODB_CONNECTIONSTR: mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
      temn.msf.security.authz.enabled: "false"
      temn.entitlement.service.enabled: "false"
      class.inbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.inbox.InboxDaoImpl
      class.outbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.outbox.OutboxDaoImpl
      className_GetDictionary: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.GetDictionaryImpl
      className_ClassifyEvnts: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.ClassifyEvntsImpl
      className_UpdateDictionary: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.UpdateDictionaryImpl
      className_PutMessagesToTopic: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.PutMessagesToTopicImpl
      temn.msf.name: ms_eventclassification      
      temn.msf.stream.vendor: kafka
      temn.msf.stream.kafka.bootstrap.servers: kafka:29092
      temn.msf.ingest.outbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      tmn.ignite.host: cache-service
      tmn.ignite.port: 10800
      

  inboxingester:
    build:
      context: ${INGESTER_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${INGESTER_APP_BASE_IMAGE}
        artifactid: ${ingester_artifactid}
        java_options: ${java_options} ${REMOTE_DEBUG}
    image: ${INGESTER_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db-service1
      - db-service2
      - db-service3
    ports:
      - "40500:40500"
    environment:
      DATABASE_KEY: mongodb
      MONGODB_DBNAME: ms_eventclassification
      MONGODB_CONNECTIONSTR: mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
      temn.msf.name: ms-eventclassification
      temn.msf.stream.vendor: kafka
      temn.msf.stream.kafka.bootstrap.servers: kafka:29092
      temn.msf.ingest.source.stream: ms-eventclassification-inbox-topic
      temn.msf.ingest.source.stream.consumergroup.id: ms-eventclassification-ingester-consumer
      temn.msf.ingest.sink.error.enabled: "false"
      temn.msf.ingest.sink.error.stream.producer.id: ms-eventclassification-ingester-error-producer
      temn.msf.ingest.generic.ingester: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.ingester.GenericCommandBinaryIngester
      temn.msf.exec.env: server
      temn.msf.raise.received.event: "true"
      class.inbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.inbox.InboxDaoImpl
      class.outbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.outbox.OutboxDaoImpl
      temn.msf.ingest.is.avro.event.ingester: "false"
      temn.msf.security.authz.enabled: "false"
      temn.msf.ingest.outbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      tmn.ignite.host: cache-service
      tmn.ignite.port: 10800
      temn.msf.ingest.inbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-inbox
    
      
  inboxoutboxprocessorapp:
    build:
      context: ${INBOXOUTBOX_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${INBOXOUTBOX_BASE_IMAGE}
        artifactid: ${inboxoutbox_artifactid}
        java_options: ${java_options} ${REMOTE_DEBUG}
    image: ${INBOXOUTBOX_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - cache-service
    ports:
      - "40514:40500"
    environment:
      DATABASE_KEY: mongodb
      MONGODB_DBNAME: ms_eventclassification
      MONGODB_CONNECTIONSTR: mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017      
      temn.msf.name: ms-eventclassification
      temn.msf.stream.vendor: kafka
      temn.msf.stream.kafka.bootstrap.servers: kafka:29092
      temn.msf.exec.env: server
      temn.msf.stream.outbox.topic:
      temn.msf.ingest.generic.ingester: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.ingester.GenericCommandBinaryIngester
      temn.msf.function.class.ClassifyEvnts: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.ClassifyEvntsImpl
      temn.msf.function.class.UpdateDictionary: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.UpdateDictionaryImpl
      temn.msf.function.class.PutMessagesToTopic: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.PutMessagesToTopicImpl
      class.package.name: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function
      class.inbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.inbox.InboxDaoImpl
      class.outbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.outbox.OutboxDaoImpl
      temn.msf.security.authz.enabled: "false"
      tmn.inbox.source.namespace: eventclassification-inbox
      tmn.outbox.source.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      temn.msf.ingest.outbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      tmn.ignite.host: cache-service
      tmn.ignite.port: 10800
      tmn.inbox.thread.pool.count: 10
      tmn.outbox.thread.pool.count: 10
```

I have split that into two files

1. DB yml
2. Ingester yml

I have copied all the DB related services to DB YML file and ingester related services to ingester YML file. Since the Ingester was dependent on the DB services, I have removed those dependencies. I should ensure that the ingester YML should run only when the db-services is completely up and running.

**db.yml**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------
#- Docker compose base definition file to run containers.
#-----------------------------------------------------------
---
version: '3.6'
services:
  db-service1:
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_DB_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    container_name: 'mongo1'
    ports:
      - "30001:27017"

  db-service2:
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_DB_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    container_name: 'mongo2'
    ports:
      - "30002:27017"

  db-service3:
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_DB_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    container_name: 'mongo3'
    ports:
      - "30003:27017"


  mongosetup:
    container_name: 'mongoinit'
    build:
      context: ${MONGO_INIT_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DB_BASE_IMAGE: ${MONGO_DB_BASE_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db-service1
      - db-service2
      - db-service3
```

**Ingester.yml**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------
#- Docker compose base definition file to run containers.
#-----------------------------------------------------------
---
version: '3.6'
services:

  inboxingester:
    build:
      context: ${INGESTER_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${INGESTER_APP_BASE_IMAGE}
        artifactid: ${ingester_artifactid}
        java_options: ${java_options} ${REMOTE_DEBUG}
    image: ${INGESTER_IMAGE}
    ports:
      - "40500:40500"
    environment:
      DATABASE_KEY: mongodb
      MONGODB_DBNAME: ms_eventclassification
      MONGODB_CONNECTIONSTR: mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
      temn.msf.name: ms-eventclassification
      temn.msf.stream.vendor: kafka
      temn.msf.stream.kafka.bootstrap.servers: kafka:29092
      temn.msf.ingest.source.stream: ms-eventclassification-inbox-topic
      temn.msf.ingest.source.stream.consumergroup.id: ms-eventclassification-ingester-consumer
      temn.msf.ingest.sink.error.enabled: "false"
      temn.msf.ingest.sink.error.stream.producer.id: ms-eventclassification-ingester-error-producer
      temn.msf.ingest.generic.ingester: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.ingester.GenericCommandBinaryIngester
      temn.msf.exec.env: server
      temn.msf.raise.received.event: "true"
      class.inbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.inbox.InboxDaoImpl
      class.outbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.outbox.OutboxDaoImpl
      temn.msf.ingest.is.avro.event.ingester: "false"
      temn.msf.security.authz.enabled: "false"
      temn.msf.ingest.outbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      tmn.ignite.host: cache-service
      tmn.ignite.port: 10800
      temn.msf.ingest.inbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-inbox
    
      
  inboxoutboxprocessorapp:
    build:
      context: ${INBOXOUTBOX_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${INBOXOUTBOX_BASE_IMAGE}
        artifactid: ${inboxoutbox_artifactid}
        java_options: ${java_options} ${REMOTE_DEBUG}
    image: ${INBOXOUTBOX_IMAGE}
    ports:
      - "40514:40500"
    environment:
      DATABASE_KEY: mongodb
      MONGODB_DBNAME: ms_eventclassification
      MONGODB_CONNECTIONSTR: mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017      
      temn.msf.name: ms-eventclassification
      temn.msf.stream.vendor: kafka
      temn.msf.stream.kafka.bootstrap.servers: kafka:29092
      temn.msf.exec.env: server
      temn.msf.stream.outbox.topic:
      temn.msf.ingest.generic.ingester: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.ingester.GenericCommandBinaryIngester
      temn.msf.function.class.ClassifyEvnts: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.ClassifyEvntsImpl
      temn.msf.function.class.UpdateDictionary: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.UpdateDictionaryImpl
      temn.msf.function.class.PutMessagesToTopic: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function.PutMessagesToTopicImpl
      class.package.name: com.myproject.microservice.eventclassification.function
      class.inbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.inbox.InboxDaoImpl
      class.outbox.dao: com.myproject.microservice.framework.core.outbox.OutboxDaoImpl
      temn.msf.security.authz.enabled: "false"
      tmn.inbox.source.namespace: eventclassification-inbox
      tmn.outbox.source.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      temn.msf.ingest.outbox.cache.namespace: eventclassification-outbox
      tmn.ignite.host: cache-service
      tmn.ignite.port: 10800
      tmn.inbox.thread.pool.count: 10
      tmn.outbox.thread.pool.count: 10
```

Is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do that. Why you would is probably personal preference. A few things to look at:

### Networking

Docker-compose will generate a default network for all services so they can connect to each other. When you bring your services up like `docker-compose -f file1.yaml -f file2.yaml up` then docker-compose will merge the yamls and create a network with name `folderName_default`. I have not tested it, but having the yamls in different folders will probably mean you have to specify a custom network, and use that network for your services.
You can also bring the services up separately, then the same goes: if they are in the same folder then that should work.

### Depends_on

If you use a `depends_on` key in your yamls, both the service depending and the service it depends on should be specified in the same yaml file OR you have to bring them up using the `docker-compose -f file1.yaml -f file2.yaml up` way, so they will be merged.

### Environment

Also, as an aside, there is a possibility to use an env file for your environment variables. This is very useful for working with multiple environments and/or long lists of variables:

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  inboxingester:
    build:
      context: ${INGESTER_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${INGESTER_APP_BASE_IMAGE}
        artifactid: ${ingester_artifactid}
        java_options: ${java_options} ${REMOTE_DEBUG}
    image: ${INGESTER_IMAGE}
    ports:
      - "40500:40500"
    env_file:
      - ./env/database-vars
      - ./env/some-other-vars
```

See also [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: These two YML files will be running on different server machines and I am struggling to establish a connection between them.

Comment: Then you prbably can not connect directly. The default driver "bridge" for networks does not allow that. Look into the [overlay](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) type. That might support it.  But I think that requires you to use swarm mode and by then you might just take the pain and go kubernetes. Or just connect like you would to any other external system I guess.